# Pipeline syntax for "Publish XML Summary Reports"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there anyway I can find Pipeline syntax for "Publish XML Summary Reports"? I have to move a project configuration from Freestyle project to Pipeline project. "Publish XML Summary Reports" is one part that is blocking the migration since I couldn't find a Pipeline syntax for the same. I am new to Jenkins and it would be helpful anyone could provide some inputs on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is for you:

```
step([$class: 'ACIPluginPublisher', name: '*.xml', shownOnProjectPage: false])
```

And you can find it from Snippet Generator as below:

[image: Snippet Generator]

Comment: how to write this in jenkins scripted format please, I found but nowhere found.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally first see which tool is producing the reports and then add a plugin in jenkins for that . For example junit test reports:

```
junit healthScaleFactor: 10.0, testResults: 'myproject/target/test-reports/*.xml'
```